# Using jquery each(), what is the best way to ensure I don't ever have more than 5 columns in this html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, each

On the callback of an ajax call i get an array of people objects with URL to their pictures.  I have the following code:

```
 html.push("<table class='tooltipProject'>");
 html.push("<tr><td>");

      $.each(data.People, function (index, person) {
         html.push("<img width='44' src='" + person.PicLink + "' />");
      });

 html.push("</td></tr>");
 html.push("</table>");
 return html.join("");
```

I am taking this html and having it show up in a popup window. This works great because each of the arrays (`data.People`) were small.  I now have situation where they are large so the UI looks too wide.  I can constrain my UI popup to be fixed width (lets say 500px) but I now need to generate a table where I don't ever want more than 5 images in a row and after that it should just to the next row

So I have 3 items in `data.People` then it will show one row.

If I have 10 items in `data.People` then I want to show 5 on row one and 5 on row 2.

I could created a TD for each picture but I am not sure that makes a difference as i still need the right logic to know when its time for a new row.

Comment: Why are you using a single-celled table for this? A `<div>` should be fine and is more semantically correct.

Comment: using this code you'll never have more than 1 column.

Comment: Why are you creating an array and adding strings, to make 1 string of it all in the end? Why not just adding it to the string?

Comment: @putvande It's an optimization. http://jsperf.com/string-concat-vs-array-join-10000/19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the index of your `$.each` loop, modulo 5, to determine when to start a row:

```
 html.push("<table class='tooltipProject'><tr>");

 $.each(data.People, function (index, person) {
     html.push("<td><img width='44' src='" + person.PicLink + "'></td>");
     if (index % 5 == 4 && index < data.People.length - 1) {
         html.push("</tr><tr>");
     }
 });

 html.push("</tr></table>");
 return html.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to just use index and an `if` statement to your code.  The result would look something like this:

```
html.push("<table class='tooltipProject'>");
html.push("<tr><td>");
  $.each(data.People, function (index, person) {
     html.push("<img width='44' src='" + person.PicLink + "' />");
     if ((index+1) % 5 == 0) {
         html.push("</td></tr><tr>");
     }
  });

html.push("</td></tr>");
html.push("</table>");
return html.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$.each(data.People, function (index, person) {
    html.push("<img width='44' src='" + person.PicLink + "' />");
    if((index+1)%5==0) html.push('</td></tr><tr><td>');
});
```

or if you decide to use div's (which is better), make that `if` statement:

```
if((index+1)%5==0) html.push('</div><div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If index is numeric you can use the modulo.

```
$.each(data.People, function (index, person) {
    html.push("<img width='44' src='" + person.PicLink + "' />");
    if ( ((index + 1) % 5) == 0) {
        html.push("</td></tr><tr><td>");
    }
});
```

`index + 1` because your first element have index = 0.